# Query execution order when multiple user access

Tags: php, mysql

When an identical PHP file is executed by users.

In what order are the MySQL queries executed? Is like this?

```
file-to-file(collect the query/by file)
Q1-Q2-Q3,Q1-Q2-Q3
```

or

```
time-to-time(according who executed first/by time)
Q1,Q1,Q2,Q2,Q3,Q3
```

Comment: I was a bit worried when many people access the same files, and when the query was submitted, they are not sequential. (more than one query in one file)

Answer (score 0):

It is basically time to time...like first come and first serve.

another interesting thing is when there is multiple users in the system, multiple php instances are running then. The php-mysql driver take care all of this and executed in parallel each instance.
and  of course for single instance the system maintain a list of job(query) according to first come first serve basis.

:)

Comment: so, the executed query order by users will be mixed(although the difference is microsecond). like: Q1,Q1,Q2,Q2...?